# Representing matrix of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

In an exercise I was given an 3d inner product space and a basis for a subspace and had to orthogonalize it and complete it into an orthogonal basis for the whole space. Then, I was told to find the minimal and characteristic polynomials for the orthogonal projection on the span of the first two basis elements.

I thought to look for the representing matrix w.r.t the orthogonal basis itself, which just gives me $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ from which I conclude $\rho (t)=t(t-1)^2$ and $m(t)=t(t-1)$, in particular orthogonal projections are always diagonalizable.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: how do you conclude that $m(t)=t(t-1)$?

Comment: @5xum representing matrix is diagonal so operator is diagonalizable so minimal polynomial has simple roots.

Comment: OK then, you are done. :)

Comment: @5xum thanks!!!